# R: Subset / index an object by substring of the wanted entries

Tags: regex, r, indexing, subset

Is it possible to extract/subset a dataframe by indicating only a chunk of the wanted entries-string?

The filter criteria is stored in an factor vector. But there are only the first three digits indicated. This should determine to subset all entries of the dataframe starting with them.

Example:

```
 # Input dataframe
 data <- read.table(header=T, text='
             ID sex size
        0120010   M    7
        0120020   F    6
        0121031   F    9
        0130010   M   11
        0130020   M   11
        0130030   F   14
        0130040   M   11
        0150030   F   11
        0150110   F   12
        0180030   F    9
        1150110   F   12
        9180030   F    9
        'colClasses =c("character", "factor", "integer"))

 # Input vector/factor with the ID chunk, containing only the fist three digits
 # of the targeted entries in data$ID
 IDfilter <- c("012", "015", "115")

 # My try/idea which sadly is not working - PLEASE HELP HERE
 subset <- data[ID %in% paste(IDfilter, "?.", sep=""),]

 # Expected subset
 > subset
           ID sex size
 1    0120010   M    7
 2    0120020   F    6
 3    0121031   F    9
 4    0150030   F   11
 5    0150110   F   12
 6    1150110   F   12
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data <- read.table(header=T, text='
             ID sex size
         0120010   M    7
        0120020   F    6
        0121031   F    9
        0130010   M   11
        0130020   M   11
        0130030   F   14
        0130040   M   11
        0150030   F   11
        0150110   F   12
        0180030   F    9
        1150110   F   12
        9180030   F    9
        ', colClasses =c("character", "factor", "integer"))

 IDfilter <- c("012", "015", "115") # filter must be character vector



   data[substr(data[,"ID"], 1,3) %in% IDfilter, ]
#        ID sex size
#1  0120010   M    7
#2  0120020   F    6
#3  0121031   F    9
#8  0150030   F   11
#9  0150110   F   12
#11 1150110   F   12
```

Note the `colClases`. In this case, `ID` is suppose to be character in order to allow the first number to be 0 as in `0120010` otherwise (if it's numeric or integer) this number would be `120010`

Another alternative is

```
data[substr(data[,"ID"], 1,nchar(IDfilter)[1]) %in% IDfilter, ]
```

where the third argument of `substr` is automatically updated to be the number of characters of the first element in `IDfileter`, the assumption here is that each number in `IDfilter` has the same number of characters.

Comment: @Jilber Nice! :) Thank you! Is the `as.numeric` part important? In my original problem I have also leading zeros.

Comment: I edited my answer to illustrate the case when leading zeroes are present. In this case, `ID` is suppose to be `character` in order to allow the first number to be `0` as in `02002` otherwise (if it's numeric or integer) this number would be `2002` .

Answer (score 2):

A regex approach:

```
subset(data, grepl(paste0("^",IDfilter,collapse="|"), ID))

        ID sex size
1  0120010   M    7
2  0120020   F    6
3  0121031   F    9
8  0150030   F   11
9  0150110   F   12
11 1150110   F   12
```

Note: "^" is to match the beginning of the string. I'm assuming there are only digits in your filters.